# Problema com read property 'query' of undefined

Tags: sql-server, node.js

Estou tendo problemas para obter o result de uma query no Nodejs
bd -SqlServer
module - mssql

Erro apresentado:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
    at FormulasDAO.getFormulas (C:\xampp\htdocs\node_fa\app\models\FormulasDAO.js:6:22)

dbConnection.js

```js
const sql = require('mssql');


var config = {
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    server: 'ip',
    database: 'name_db',
    connectionTimeout: '5000',
    requestTimeout: '5000',
    options: {encrypt: true}
};


var pool = function(){
    var conn =  new sql.ConnectionPool(config, function(err){
        var request = new sql.Request(conn);
        //console.dir(request);
        return request;
    });
    return conn;
}

module.exports = function(){
    return pool;
}
```

FormulasDAO.js

```js
function FormulasDAO(connection) {
    this._connection = connection;
}

FormulasDAO.prototype.getFormulas = (callback)=>{
    this._connection.query('select * from usuario', callback);
}

module.exports = function() {
    return FormulasDAO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O erro acima se da por conta da forma que estava escrevendo o código com arrowFunction onde o mesmo possui um contexto global, segue abaixo a resolução do problema:

```js
//Antes
FormulasDAO.prototype.getFormulas = (callback)=>{
    this._connection.query('select * from usuario', callback);
}

//Depois

FormulasDAO.prototype.getFormulas = function(callback){
    this._connection.query('select * from usuario', callback);
}
```